# add/embed generated QR code(Image) to other Image(photo) using meanstack,angularjs,nodejs.

Tags: jquery, python, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

add/embed generated QR code(Image) to other Image(photo) using meanstack,angularjs,nodejs.

i have generated qr code using angluar-qrcode & qrcode-generator.

now i want to attch/add/embed this qr code to another picture.
i dont have any idea.
is this possible?

```
 <script src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular-qrcode/angular-qrcode.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="qrcode-generator/js/qrcode.js"> </script>

<qrcode data="string" download></qrcode>
```